# Sard's theorem and the measure of the set of critical points

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, smooth-manifolds

The origin of my question is derived from the following theorem

**Theorem**: *Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be a map of class $\mathcal{C}^1$. Then, the following phrases are equivalents [1]:*

*a) rank $f'(x) =n$, for almost every $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$;*

*b) Let $E\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, if $\mu(E)=0\Rightarrow \mu(f^{-1}(E))=0$*,

*where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure.*

I would like to check condition a). I know that, from Sard's theorem, $\mu(f(B))=0$, where $B=\{x:rank f'(x)<n\}$. So, I can now ask:

Is there any condition on $f$ for which $\mu(B)=0$?

References:

[1] Ponomarev, S. P. - Submersions and preimages of sets of measure zero. Siberian Mathematical Journal

Comment: The set of critical points of a function is rarely null - e.g. constant functions. The theorem you quote is just providing a necessary and sufficient condition for this.

Comment: To the contrary, @hot_queen, for generic $C^1$ maps $f$, the set of points where $\text{rank}(f'(x))<n$ is a hypersurface and has measure $0$. But I don't know any condition other than the hypothesis itself.

Comment: By "rarely", I did not mean "meager many".

Comment: Thank you for the answers.

@TedShifrin, do you have a reference where I could check for a prove of what you said?

Comment: A standard book reference is Morris Hirsch's *Differential Topology*.